# Create and sort questions in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I am working on a survey app in which the user can create questions, but I want them to also sort the question in the same view.
To accomplish the questions feature I'm using the same procedures like in "Drifting Ruby"
video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56xjUOAAZY8

Here is the code of my NEW view

```
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f|%> 
  <table summary='Project form fields'>
    <tr>
      <th>Name : </th>
      <td><%= f.input_field(:name)%></td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
  <div id='questions' class='list-group' data-url="sort_path">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :questions do |question| %>
      <%= question.input :title%>     
      <%= question.input :field_type%>                 
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add question', f, :questions, class: "btn btn-outline-info" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= f.submit 'Create project' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want the user to sort with drag and drop the questions he just created with the button "add question", something like the following image.
[sort expectation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrPgs.png)

I found similar actions, but they sort the questions when they are already created and just list them out.
For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aru-XvzzGjU

Versions: ruby '2.5.1' & rails, '~> 5.2.0'

I'm new to rails so any Tip & observation will be really really helpful. thank you guys for your time and attention

Comment: I think you need some jQuery, check this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised

Comment: Do you already have some js code or is this more of an exploratory question, you need help in getting started with the drap/drop sorting? In which case imho http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ is maybe a good starting point?

Comment: I already add the gems "jquery-ui-rails" and "acts_as_list" but the thing is that I dont know how to make the new positions persist in rails database.